# can we replace $n$ with $y\in\Bbb{R}^+$ in Riemann's Lemma?

Tags: calculus, integration

Riemann's lemma:

$f\in R[a,b]$, $g(x+T)=g(x)$ and $g(x) \in R[0,T]$, we have:$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_a^bf(x)g(nx)\mathscr{dx}=\frac{1}{T}\int_a^bf(x)\mathscr{dx}\int_0^Tg(x)\mathscr{dx}$$

can we replace $n$ with $y\in\Bbb{R}^+$, does the below equality hold?:
$$\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} \int_a^bf(x)g(yx)\mathscr{dx}=\frac{1}{T}\int_a^bf(x)\mathscr{dx}\int_0^Tg(x)\mathscr{dx}$$

Thanks very much.

Comment: Yes of course you can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof for the above lemma was [posted on ME](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157016/a-problem-about-riemann-lebesgue-lemma). You can see that if you replace $n$ by $\lfloor y \rfloor$ the proof stays valid, and the series $b_n = b_{\lfloor y \rfloor}$ still converges to $b$.

So in short: Yes.